# Problem with Object Literal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and I have some isse while using Literal object, I trie to store HTML element in it with a boolean to check if my item is "clicked", here is my code :

```js
function deplacer(argument) {
 for(e in actif){
  if(actif[e] == true){
   e.style.top = argument.clientY + "px";
   e.style.left = argument.clientX + "px";
  }
 }
}

function activerDeplacement(arg) {
 actif[arg.target] = true;
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", deplacer);

var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".draggableBox");
var actif = {};

for (var i = 0, taille = elements.length; i < taille; ++i){
 actif[elements[i]] = false;
 elements[i].addEventListener("mousedown", activerDeplacement);
}
```

```css
.draggableBox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px; height: 60px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    background-color: #222;
    color: #CCC;
    cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Page drag and drop</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div class="draggableBox">1</div>
 <div class="draggableBox">2</div>
 <div class="draggableBox">3</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I do this, there is only one element when I use for in and it have an undefined type..

I'm really lost and if you can help me it would be so cool !
Thank you in advance !

edit : I found the problem ! I can't store reference as element in Literal Object, so to resolve my problem I did this :

```
function deplacer(argument) {
    if(actif){
        actif.style.top = argument.clientY +"px";
        actif.style.left = argument.clientX + "px";
    }
}

function activerDeplacement(arg) {
    actif = arg.target;
}

function desactiverDeplacement(arg) {
    actif = null;
}

document.addEventListener("mousemove", deplacer);

var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".draggableBox");
var actif = null;

for (var i = 0, taille = elements.length; i < taille; ++i){
    elements[i].addEventListener("mousedown", activerDeplacement);
    elements[i].addEventListener("mouseup", desactiverDeplacement);
}
```

And now everything work fine !

Comment: object names get turned to strings you havent got html elements to reference

Comment: oh, you mean I can't store reference in Literal Object ?

Comment: not as its key to look up

Comment: hope my answer clears it up any questions let me know

Comment: I've updated so it drags all of them please leave if upvote if ive helped :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`actif[elements[i]] = false;` isnt saving the html element its transforming the object reference into a string`[object HTMLDivElement]`

```js
console.log(String(document.querySelector('div')))
console.log(String(document.querySelector('div')).style)
```

```html
<div></div>
```

```js
const actif = {};
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".draggableBox");

document.addEventListener("mousemove", deplacer);

elements.forEach(init)

function init(element, index) {
  actif[index] = {
    active: false,
    element
  };
  element.addEventListener("mousedown", activerDeplacement);
  element.addEventListener("mouseup", e => activerDeplacement(e, false));
}

function deplacer(argument) {
  Object
    .values(actif)
    .forEach(e => assignXY(argument, e))
}

function assignXY(argument, { active, element }) {
  if (active) {
    element.style.top = argument.clientY + "px";
    element.style.left = argument.clientX + "px";
  }
}

function activerDeplacement(arg, active = true) {
  Object.assign(getFromEvent(arg), { active });
}

function getFromEvent({ target }) {
  return actif[Array.from(elements).indexOf(target)];
}
```

```css
.draggableBox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 60px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #CCC;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Page drag and drop</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="draggableBox">1</div>
  <div class="draggableBox">2</div>
  <div class="draggableBox">3</div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```